# Using Include to Get Property Inside of a Collection

Tags: entity-framework-6

My model has 3 (relevant) objects:

```
public class A
{
   public long Id {get;set;}
   public virtual long List<B> Bs {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
  public long Id {get;set;}
  public int Order {get;set;}
  public virtual C @C {get;set;}
}

public class C
{
  public long Id {get;set;}
  public sting Value {get;set;}
}
```

I am trying to write a linq statement that will start at `A` and include both `B` and `C`... Something like (I know this doesn't work, but I don't know how else to express the general idea)

```
ctxt.A.Include(a=>a.Bs.C).ToList();
```

The sql I am trying to generate would be something like:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM A

JOIN BtoA ba ON ba.Aid = A.Id

JOIN B ON ba.Bid = B.Id

JOIN C ON C.Id = B.Cid
```

How to do this?

EDIT:

My question is more about how to get EF to pull this data in a single query than how to get the data itself.

Comment: Which approach do you use? Db first or code first?

Comment: Have you tried `ctxt.A.Include(a=>a.Bs.Select(b => b.C)).ToList();`?

Comment: I am using Code First

Comment: @nemesv your suggestion worked! add it as an answer so I can give you your reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to eagerly load multiple levels of related entities.

If your related entities (`C`) are part of a collection (`B`) then you need to write a `Select` inside the `Include`:

```
ctxt.A.Include(a=>a.Bs.Select(b => b.C)).ToList();
```

See also the documentation: [Eagerly loading multiple levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eagerLevels)

Comment: I cant award the bounty for another 19 hours, but it is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you use db first or code first approach, but in db first I would do it like that:

- create a db view

  CREATE VIEW MySchema.MyView AS
  SELECT
    *
  FROM A
  JOIN BtoA ba ON ba.Aid = A.Id
  JOIN B ON ba.Bid = B.Id
  JOIN C ON C.Id = B.Cid
- Then, after updating the model from db, I would use this view to display the data (which is what I suppose you are trying to do)

Actually in code first approach in EF 6 you can also create views:

```
//Figure 8 Using the New CreateView Operation

public partial class AddView : DbMigration
  {
    public override void Up()
    {
      this.CreateView("MySchema.MyView",
                      @"SELECT *
                        FROM A
                        JOIN BtoA ba ON ba.Aid = A.Id    
                        JOIN B ON ba.Bid = B.Id    
                        JOIN C ON C.Id = B.Cid");
    }
    public override void Down()
    {
      this.RemoveView("dbo.CasinosWithOver100SlotMachines");
    }
  }
```

As stated here (Figure 8):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn519921.aspx